# REST API in 'Send a HTTP Request' returning an error

Tags: rest, flow, json

I'm trying to return an additional SP column in a Flow I've inherited. I've checked the name of the field in the address bar and it's showing as 'BTG%5Fx0020%5FPolicy%5Fx0020%5FOwner'. I've added it to the Uri but I'm getting the following error:

The query to field  is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains BTG_x0020_Policy_x0020_Owner.The BTG_x00200 field is a People Picker field.

This is how I've written it, but I can't see where I'm going wrong? all help appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$expand` to specify the fields where you want to get sub properties. `$select` is used to indicate which sub properties. It can be pretty confusing.

So your `$select` needs to specify the sub properties you want to return. For instance `$select=Title,BTG_x0020_Policy_x0020_Owner/Title,BTG_x0020_Policy_x0020_Owner/EMail&$expand=BTG_x0020_Policy_x0020_Owner`

You don't need to include `Title` in your expand list.